# Zend Framework XML-RPC?

Tags: zend-framework, xml-rpc

I would like to build an XML over HTTP provisioning interface using Zend Framework. Should Zend_XmlRpc_Server be used for this purpose? If so, can you recommend any guides on using it? (Specifically the part retrieving incoming XML and parsing it.)

Comment: Great article by the ZF lead : http://mwop.net/blog/227-Exposing-Service-APIs-via-Zend-Framework. That is what I use to build a basic API, but I am pretty sure you can build on that to make something really robust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of service is it? - will you send binary data or rather short texts? Will all clients be in PHP mostly or you are foreseeing a wide range of clients?
Usually if you're doing a web-based small service, REST will do the trick, it's easy to develop and consume, even by plain JS frontends, such as jQuery.
If it's something more complex, you can't go wrong with SOAP, though it's a bit complex in developing. Make sure you arm yourself with [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org)

XmlRPC has some limitations, especially sending binary data. There's some thorough comparison to have a look at [this blog](http://michaeldehaan.net/2008/07/17/xmlrpc-vs-rest-vs-soap-vs-all-your-rpc-options/)